# Setting OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create something like favorite thing in my app 
I have made activity with restaurant which can be set as favorite, I've made imagebutton for making restaurant favorite and it's working, cause I have second activity where list is getting info from database and everything is ok. Titles match, adresses match cities too, so database should match too. 
I have problem with changing OnClickListener, I want to use info from database to check if String called "database_name" is matching with any string from database. 
There is code for it :

```
mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
final SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

String[] selection = {FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATABASE};
favoriteButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favoriteRestaurant);

Cursor cursor = db.query(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection,
                null, null, null, null, null);

if(cursor.getCount() != 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            if(cursor.getString(0).toLowerCase() == database_name.toLowerCase()){
                favoriteButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favoritet));
                isFavorite = 1;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

It's changing background of this favorite button to filled heart, at least it's supposed to do so. In default it's not filled. 
 
Then I'm changing onClickListener, code for it looks like this :

```
if(isFavorite == 0) {
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isntFavorite();
        }
    });
} else {
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isFavorite();
        }
    });
}
```

isFavorite look like this :

```
private void isFavorite() {
        favoriteButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favoriteu));
    String selection = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATABASE + " LIKE ?";
    mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { database_name };

    db.delete(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isntFavorite();
        }
    });
}
```

And code for isntFavorite looks like this:

```
private void isntFavorite() {
    favoriteButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favoritet));
    mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, restaurantName);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ADRESS, restaurantAdress);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CITY, restaurantCity);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATABASE, database_name);
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null, values);
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isFavorite();
        }
    });
}
```

The thing is that it's always changing onClickListener to isntFavorite and it's not changing image background to filled heart, even if there is matching data in database. I was trying to change matching title from database to title from activity, and I was sure that they're matching cause there was in list title with the same String as title from activity where I was trying to match them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to change OnclickListener just create a boolean to save the state:

```
final boolean state = isFavorite == 0;
    favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     boolean mState = state;  
      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if(mState)isntFavorite();
           else isFavorite();
           mState=!mState;
        }
    });

private void isFavorite() {
    favoriteButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favoriteu));
    String selection = FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATABASE + " LIKE ?";
    mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { database_name };
    db.delete(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);

}

private void isntFavorite() {
    favoriteButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.favoritet));
    mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, restaurantName);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ADRESS, restaurantAdress);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_CITY, restaurantCity);
    values.put(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_DATABASE, database_name);
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(FeedReaderContract.FeedEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                null, values);

}
```

Comment: But this activity is starting from list and it's taking data about restaurant from previous activity so it cannot use saved state, it has t check if database_name taken from previous acitvity is matching any of database_name in SQLite Database

Comment: As I can see, when you call isFavorite() for example, you are directly put a new OnClickListener now changing to isntFavorite(), before you have isFavorite to get the first value, as I post it, There is another way when you change the favoriteButton Listener?

Comment: I'd considered the first value in: final boolean state isFavorite == 0;

Comment: isFavorite without () is int which is in default equal 0, cause in default restaurant isn't favourite then app is checking if there is any matching database_name in database with database_name from previous acitvity and if there is something matching it's changing isFavorite value to 1 and after checking app is changing onClickListener which depends on isFavorite variable, if it's 1 it should have to run isFavorite() if it's 0 it should run isntFavorite()

Comment: Yes, for that I've consider it in:  final boolean state isFavorite == 0;

Comment: sorry, as I could see I forgot something.

Comment: I've considered the first time as final boolean state =  isFavorite == 0; (I forgot the "=")

Comment: I don't know what do you want me to do with this final boolean state, can you tell me what should I replace with code you posted in first answer

Comment: It's ok, I don't have to use a lot of setOnClickListeners, but my problem isn't solved. I have problem that app is somehow always running as this restaurant is not favorite, even if everything is matching and that restaurant should be shown as favorite and imagebutton should change to filled heart

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not related with SQLiteDatabase on Android, I'm not sure where method insert() or update() have to be used.